# Words to mention examples of something

Tags: phrase-request

I wrote this sentence

> *curSection* is a label used to specify a major structural part of the page. **Example values** are header, footer, sidebar....

As I searched google I didn't find much cases for "example values", what is the proper words or constructions to mention examples of something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly off topic, but I would not use "are" there unless I was positive I was providing a complete list. Rather I would say "include" or "could be". With that out of way, some other ways to write it would be:

- examples include...
- some options are...
- some possibilities are...
- e.g. (This is a Latin abbreviation that means "for example". It is in common usage, but it commonly confused with i.e., which means basically "that is to say". e.g. would be appropriate if you are only listing some of the values. i.e. would be appropriate if you are listing all of the possible values.

Answer (score 0):

Just use "Examples are header, ..." or "For example, header, ..." .

Also, I am not comfortable with the "a" in "used to specify **a** major ..."  Are you sure about the indefiniteness of the article?

Comment: you suggest to use "major structural parts"? it could be too.

Comment: that is the only way? as you note, I requested for more options. how about "sample values" or "samples of values"....

Comment: the *curSection* can get one value at the time, then maybe for this reason I used *a major ...*.... could it be a valid reason?

Comment: As I don't know the role that label plays or how many of them are to be on a page (or on the page), I can't really recommend anything without getting into the details of your design (which I don't have the time for, sorry).  "Sample values"...  Is "header" a "value"?  Is "footer"?

Comment: Perhaps, "*curSection* is the label used to specify a major structural part of the page.", since you can assign different values to 'curSection', as I begin to understand...  Also, 'values' are for 'curSection' label, yes?

Comment: Yes, maybe I should say, *curSection* a property to specify ....

Comment: "curSection is a label use to specify a major structural part of the page" is completely correct if there are multiple options for labels, and multiple structural parts on a page. That is how I would expect to see that written in a programming book